# Как задать ширину макета через @media-screen для телефона?

Tags: html, css

Как задать ширину макета через [@media](/users/3055/mediaportal)-screen для телефона?
Заходя на сайт со смартфона, макет открывается как на компьютере.

В браузере же, при уменьшении ширины, элементы как нужно трансформируются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Небольшая поправочка, вместо ";" нужно ","

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Answer (score 0):

как вариант сначала задаете общие стили без медиа-скрин, которые будут применяться в первую очередь для телефонов. А затем уже специфические, например, для компов:
[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal) (min-width:800px){ ......}

Answer (score 0):

У меня вот так реализовано: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/vtuW6MCu)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 1002px) and (max-width: 1247px)" href="http://magnitog.ru/templates/adaptive/css/978.css" />-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1001px)" href="http://magnitog.ru/templates/adaptive/css/748.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px)" href="http://magnitog.ru/templates/adaptive/css/300.css" />

        <!--[if lte IE 8]>

       <script type="text/javascript" src="http://magnitog.ru/templates/adaptive/js/jquery.media-query.min.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript">
               $(function() {
                      $.mediaquery([
                             //{minWidth: 1248, maxWidth: 1407, href: 'http://magnitog.ru/templates/adaptive/css/1218.css'},
                             //{minWidth: 1002, maxWidth: 1247, href: 'http://magnitog.ru/templates/adaptive/css/978.css'},
                             {minWidth: 768, maxWidth: 1001, href: 'http://magnitog.ru/templates/adaptive/css/748.css'},
                             {minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 767, href: 'http://magnitog.ru/templates/adaptive/css/300.css'}
                      ]);
               });
       </script>
       <![endif]-->
```